# Internal Speakers are not working, but headphone jack is working fine, with Realtek ALC269VC Codec

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

Recently I bought Infinix Y4 Max laptop and replaced the preinstalled Windows with Ubuntu 22.04. Everything is working fine except the internal speaker (also fast charging is not happening but that's not much of an issue) but audio is working fine from headphone jack. It shows `Speakers (unavailable)` in audio settings. Currently it's on `Linux 6.5.0-15-generic x86_64` kernel. I used `alsamixer` to change volume and mute/unmute and `hdajackretask` to change unconnected pins or whatever that is, still no success. I googled and check many pages related to this codec but no solution helped in my case. Would could be the reason for this issue? speaker worked fine in windows tho.

all the system information is in this link. https://termbin.com/mhzu

---

**Partially solved**

After going through [this page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html)  and some trial and error and I find out that adding `options snd_hda_intel model=dell-inspiron-7559` at the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` works better for my laptop. The internal speakers are working now but the headset microphone are not. I tried many model code and figure out that with `alc288-dell1`, `alc288-dell-xps13`, `alc298-dell1` and `alc298-spk-volume`, the headset microphone are working but internal speakers are not. So either internal speaker will work or headset microphone.

Comment: Perhaps this is not the answer for your configuration but I solved my headphone-speaker conflict with this:

sudo apt-get install -y libcanberra-pulse

My system is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. :/

Comment: I was reading your https://termbin.com/mhzu. One section says
Sink #0
 State: SUSPENDED
Let's look for a way to get it into State: RUNNING

Comment: Also noted you have an entry for vdownmix - is there is a way to turn that off temporarily?